# Zendesk API using PHP: dynamic content updateMany gives invalid attribute error

Tags: php, api, zendesk

I try to update a dynamic content field via Zendesk API using PHP API client (https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/api-clients/php):

```
// auth and config goes here...    
$itemId = 123;
$variantId = 456;    
$data = [
  'id'        => $variantId,
  'content'   => 'my example content'
];
$zendesk->dynamicContent()->items($itemId)->variants()->updateMany(['variants' => $data]);
```

I get an UnknownAttributeError ("Invalid attribute: missing variants parameter"). What did I miss? I tried different ways to give the variant parameter but still the same error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

must follow the Format as like Ticket -> updateMany()

Refer [Ticket Update Many Test File](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php/blob/master/tests/Zendesk/API/LiveTests/TicketsTest.php)

```
 $itemId    = 12345;
 $variantIds = [456,787];
 $this->assertEndpointCalled(function () use ($itemId, $variantIds) {
 $this->client->dynamicContent()->items($itemId)->variants()->updateMany(
                    [
                        'ids'    => $variantIds 
                        'content' => 'My Example Content'
                    ]
                );
 }, "dynamic_content/items/$itemId/variants/update_many.json");
```